# Which provision in C99 forbids definition of a function through typedef?

Tags: c, function, c99

I know that a function definition can't be done through typedef.
For example:

```
typedef int f_t(int x, int y);

f_t fsum
{
    int sum;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}
```

But I can't find the provision which forbids this definition in C99. Which provisions are related and how they forbid this definition?

Comment: Related: [Why can't a typedef of a function be used to define a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17848983/1009479)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is immediately given in the clause describing function definitions:

> #### 6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> Constraints
>
> 2 - The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition.<sup>141)</sup>
>
> 141) The intent is that the type category in a function definition cannot be inherited from a typedef [...]

The way this works is that under declarators (6.7.5), the only function declarators (6.7.5.3) are those with parentheses after the identifier:

> `T D(` *parameter-type-list* `)`
>   `T D(` *identifier-list<sub>opt</sub>* `)`

So, if the function is defined via a typedef then it does not have the syntactic form of a function declarator and so is invalid by 6.9.1p2.

It may help to consider the syntactic breakdown of an attempted typedef function definition:

```
typedef int F(void);

F f {}
| | ^^-- compound-statement
| ^-- declarator
^-- declaration-specifiers
```

Note that the typedef type `F` is part of the *declaration-specifiers* and not part of the *declarator*, and so `f` (the declarator portion) does not have a function type.

Comment: I have read this provision, but I can't understand how we get the intent.

Comment: Does that provision require a function declarator? It just requires a declarator. The 'fsum' is a legal declarator.

Comment: @junwanghe 'fsum' is a declarator, but without the declaration-specifier `f_t` it does not have a function type.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking about the *intent* of forbidding typedefs from being used in a function definition (in some comments), the C99 rationale has this to say about it:

> An argument list must be explicitly present in the declarator; it
>   cannot be inherited from a typedef (see §6.7.5.3).  That is to say,
>   given the definition:
>
> ```
> typedef int p(int q, int r);
> ```
>
> the following fragment is invalid:
>
> ```
> p funk  // weird 
> { return q + r ; }
> ```

So it seems that the function defintion-by-typedef was disallowed because the definition didn't look enough like a function in that case.