# Declaring member function using function type syntax

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, cl

Just recently I learned that you can declare a function (including methods) using variable-like syntax with function type:

```
using function_type = int (double);
// pre-C++11:
//typedef int function_type(double);

function_type fun_global;

struct methods
{
    static function_type mem_fun_static;
    function_type mem_fun_normal;
    virtual function_type mem_fun_virtual;
    virtual function_type mem_fun_abstract = 0;
};
```

In above code

- `fun_global` is a global function,
- `mem_fun_static` is a `static` member function,
- `mem_fun_normal` is an ordinary method,
- `mem_fun_virtual` is a `virtual` method,
- `mem_fun_abstract` is an abstract method.

All of them take single argument of type `double` and return `int` value - just like the `function_type` says.

All this years I know C++ and I didn't know about this - this language never stops surprising me! By the way - is this syntax mentioned anywhere [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)? I don't see this...

However, while exploring this new to me feature I stumbled upon some inconsistencies between compilers. For tests, I was using following compilers:

- GCC 5.4.0 and 7.1.0, command line: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14`
- Clang 4.0.1, command line: `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14`
- MSVC 19.10.25019 (VS 2017), command line: `cl /W4 /EHsc`

In tests that I run both GCC versions gave same result so further I'm referring to them just as GCC.

---

### `= delete` inconsistency

```
struct methods
{
    /* ... */
    function_type mem_fun_deleted = delete;
};
```

- GCC: OK
- Clang: **error!**

  ```
  Test.cpp:13:34: error: '= delete' is a function definition and must occur in a standalone declaration
          function_type mem_fun_deleted = delete;
                                          ^
  1 error generated.
  ```
- MSVC: OK

### `= default` inconsistency

```
struct methods
{
    /* ... */
    using assignment_type = methods& (methods const&);
    assignment_type operator= = default;
};
```

- GCC: OK
- Clang: **error!**

  ```
  Test.cpp:14:30: error: '= default' is a function definition and must occur in a standalone declaration
          assignment_type operator= = default;
                                      ^
  1 error generated.
  ```
- MSVC: **error!**

  ```
  Test.cpp(14): error C2206: 'methods::operator =': typedef cannot be used for function definition
  ```

### Inline definition inconsistency

```
struct methods
{
    /* ... */
    function_type mem_fun_inline { return 0; }
};
```

- GCC: **error!**

  ```
  Test.cpp:13:43: error: invalid initializer for member function ‘int methods::mem_fun_inline(double)’
    function_type mem_fun_inline { return 0; }
                                             ^
  Test.cpp:13:43: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
  ```
- Clang: **error!**

  ```
  Test.cpp:13:33: error: expected expression
          function_type mem_fun_inline { return 0; }
                                         ^
  Test.cpp:7:8: error: missing '}' at end of definition of 'methods'
  struct methods
         ^
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/c++config.h:194:1: note: still within definition of 'methods' here
  namespace std
  ^
  2 errors generated.
  ```
- MSVC: OK

---

### Questions

**Which compilers are right here?**

Furthermore, is it possible to:

1. In the inline definition (supported only by MSVC) refer somehow to the argument?
2. Somehow use the `function_type` also at definition of those functions (when done outside of the class). Following is OK (with all compilers)

   ```
   struct methods
   {
       static function_type mem_fun_static;
       /* ... */
   };

   int methods::mem_fun_static(double) { return 0; }
   ```

   It is not that bad since change of `function_type` should result in compilation error at function definition (as it will no longer match declaration) - but still maybe it is possible to avoid even that.

Comment: Nice question! Was aware of it, but saw little practical use beyond specifying the types of expected callback functions (mostly in C code as well).

Comment: @StoryTeller That is actually how I found it out! - "thread main" callback with the framework we have.

Comment: Amazing how the forward declarations of those functions become self explanatory, isn't it? I also like that pointer semantics aren't being hidden behind an alias.

Comment: BTW, it can also be used as a type parameter to `std::function`. Again, more self documenting code.

Comment: While phrased differently, this is basically a duplicate of [Why can't a typedef of a function be used to define a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848983/why-cant-a-typedef-of-a-function-be-used-to-define-a-function)

Comment: @underscore_d - I disagree. That question is about the rationale for the standard's position. This is about "what is the standard's position".

Comment: @StoryTeller I kinda see what you mean, but to me, 'Can I do X?' is a subset of 'Why can I not do X?'; an answer explaining the position inherently identifies what it is. If the latter has already been answered, then IMO we don't need the former.

Comment: @underscore_d Before asking I was searching and did not find that one. :(

Comment: @AdamBadura It may not have been your fault! I sometimes find that Googling for _foo bar stackoverflow_ produces more useful results than SO's own duplicate-finder, which is unfortunate but still a handy backup.

Comment: @underscore_d But at least my question adds comparison between 3 compilers and perhaps someone should now issue bug tickets against MSVC and GCC. :)

Comment: @AdamBadura I tend to nominate the person who found the bugs to report them... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> § 8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct] p12 A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function.

Thus Clang is right to reject the code in all cases and compilers that accept it are in the wrong.

(The quotation is from N4618 but the rule is a part of the language since forever).

Comment: What revision are you quoting? Could you please add the section name as well? (Section names are stable across revisions, numbers not so much).

Comment: I'm surprised that `= delete` counts as function definition. If you could provide a quote for that as well it would be even better. But your answer answers it all, so thanks!

Comment: @AdamBadura 8.4.3 \[dcl.fct.def.delete\] "A function definition of the form ... is called a deleted definition".